# Jquery result message not defined

Tags: jquery, ajax

This used to work, but somehow it wont work anymore.
I am getting a Uncaught ReferenceError: msg is not defined (it refers to the success function)
Weird thing is, it shouldnt successed as the server is down.
Even if the server is up, it gives me the same error.

```
function login(user, pass){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://XX.XX.XXX.XX:8080/wcf/Service1.svc/HentBruger",
        data: '{"username":"'+user+'", "password":"'+pass+'"}',
         processData: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: loginsuccess(msg),
        error: loginfailed(msg),

    });

}
```

I'd prefer using this code as it gives me timeout possibilities. But also.. same error, msg is not defined in the done section

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://XX.XX.XXX.XX:8080/wcf/Service1.svc/HentBruger",
    data: '{"username":"someuser", "password":"somepass"}',
    timeout:5000
}).done(function( msg ){
   alert( msg );
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
    if(textStatus == 'timeout')
    {     
        alert('Failed from timeout'); 
        //do something. Try again perhaps?
    }
});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using ? The promise version isn't available before 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
    success: loginsuccess(msg),
    error: loginfailed(msg),
```

to

```
    success: loginsuccess,
    error: loginfailed,
```

Instead of setting `loginsuccess` as callback, you were setting the return of `loginsuccess(msg)`, with `msg` still undefined.

---

In both case, you may be subject to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) : you may read in javascript the result of a JSON request sent to another origin only if the distant site has set [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP_access_control).

Comment: I was going to post this too for the first part, but was stuck pondering the second part. Any idea why that's not working?

Comment: loginsuccess and loginfailed are functions i made by myself. Will try the second part as it's the most important

Comment: @dystroy: i am looking at this page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. Near the end he have this: .done(function(msg) {
  $("#log").html( msg );
});

Comment: @BenLee For a recent jQuery, all that I can think about is the lack of CORS headers.

Comment: Good idea about the CORS headers -- I bet that's it! Didn't occur to me to look at the url the OP was actually using, very likely to be a different origin.

Comment: Thought about the CORS headers. I am currently using a wamp server running locally (apache and jquery running on it). The service i am requesting from is an IIS server running remotely. Where do i add the cors headers? i've added them on the IIS server, but cant figure out where to do it in wamp

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your response. The problem have been solved. I have no idea how, what I know after this experience is that wamps allow origin policy is set to localhost only. and phonegaps allow origins policy is set to *

This is whats working:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST", //This was set to GET
    url: "http://XX.XX.XXX.XX:8080/wcf/Service1.svc/HentBruger",
    data: '{"username":"something", "password":"somepass"}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //I've forgot those
    dataType: "json", //I've forgot those
    timeout:5000 
}).success(function( msg ){
   document.write(msg);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
alert(textStatus); //returns an error, not timeout. But i am recieving something on failure..
    if(textStatus == 'timeout')
    {     
        alert('Failed from timeout'); 
        //do something. Try again perhaps?
    }
});
```

Also, i've added allow origin policy * to my IIS server. not sure if that done anything.